# Cannot see anything in the console when trying to debug a login function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am using Node.js with Express as well as Pug templates. I have a login function that is not working. I am trying to debug the code by logging the credentials (email and password) to the console. But I cannot see anything in the console.

Here is a code snippet:

```
const loginForm = document.querySelector('.form--login');

if (loginForm)
  loginForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    console.log(email, password);
    login(email, password);
  });
```

I have tested to see if the if statement works and it does because I placed a console.log statement in the beginning like this:

```
if (loginForm) console.log('True');
```

I can see the word True in the console, which proves that the responses are correct up to that point.

I also placed the following statement after the `const loginForm...`

```
console.log(loginForm)
```

I can see `<form class="form form--login"></form>` in the console.

But the console.log in the eventListener function produces nothing. Even if I place some text into the console.log statement, I cannot see it. It's as if the program never gets to that point.

Why is this happening?

Here is the HTML in Pug form:

```
extends base

block content
    main.main
    .login-form
        h2.heading-secondary.ma-bt-lg Log into your account
        form.form.form--login
        .form__group
            label.form__label(for='email') Email address
            input#email.form__input(type='email', placeholder='you@example.com', required)
        .form__group.ma-bt-md
            label.form__label(for='password') Password
            input#password.form__input(type='password', placeholder='••••••••', required, minlength='8')
        .form__group
           a.buttonS.primaryD1.fontStd(href='/login')  Login
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to capture an event, that does never fire in the first place. `a.buttonS.primaryD1.fontStd(href='/login')  Login ` - pretty sure that will render a _link_, and not a submit button. So your form doesn't have an actual submit button then, and any functionality happening when you click that link, must already be implemented in JavaScript, instead of relying on standard form submission ...?

Comment: are you looking in the right place for the console.log output? i.e. in the browser, since that's where the console.log is taking place

Comment: `input(type='submit')` may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple issues. First, if you look at the compiled HTML, you'll notice the `<form>` element will be empty because nothing is indented underneath it in the Pug.

```
// current pug
form.form.form--login
.form__group

// what it needs to be
form.form.form--login
  .form__group // <-- indent to put the form groups in the form
```

Second, the `console.log()` will only be triggered when the form submits—and `<a>` elements won't submit forms by default. That "Login" link should probably be a submit `<button>`:

```
// current pug
a.buttonS.primaryD1.fontStd(href='/login')  Login 

// what it should probably be
button.buttonS.primaryD1.fontStd(type='submit') Log In
```

---

Working snippet with compiled HTML:

```js
const loginForm = document.querySelector('.form--login');

if (loginForm)
  loginForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    console.log(email, password);
  });
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <div class="login-form">
    <h2>Log into your account</h2>
    <form class="form--login">
      <div class="form__group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" required="required"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" required="required" minlength="8"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group">
        <button type="submit">Log In</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks Sean and @Cbroe. Your comments are helpful, but the problem persists - no change.

Comment: @Leon I've edited my answer with a snippet that shows the suggestions do resolve the problem and the `console.log()` works. If you've verified your compiled HTML matches this and you still don't see the `console.log()`, the issue is elsewhere in the code. Are there any errors in the console?